# Proving at most one affine permutation mapping $x$ to $u$ and $y$ to $v$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\gcd(x−y,n) = 1$

Tags: substitution-cipher, permutation, affine-cipher

Suppose that $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ with $\gcd(x−y,n) = 1$. Prove that for any $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ there is at most one affine permutation mapping $x$ to $u$ and $y$ to $v$.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. This is clearly a dump of homework. Where you stuck?

Comment: start with the definition of a permutation.